# Laptop randomly powers off; this does not seem to be caused by any of the common causes

Tags: laptop, power, shutdown

This started happening yesterday: My laptop will shut down at random. Immediately after shutting down, it becomes difficult to turn back on (i.e., it'll sometimes turn on for a second, then shut off again. Other times it will turn on and work as intended).

Some oddities:

- At some point a couple of weeks ago, I did notice tiny electrical stings coming from the corners of this laptop while it sat on my lap.
- It shuts down far more often when I'm on Windows than when I'm on Linux

To no avail, I have:

- Purchased a new charging cable
- Opened the laptop and gave it a thorough cleaning
- Monitored the temperatures of the processor, graphics card, and other hardware (it all typically stays below 65-deg.C)
- Attempted to start/run the computer connected to AC power *without* the battery. It will sometimes run as normal, and is *more difficult* to turn on (i.e., it takes more pressing-the-power-button attempts to turn on and remain on), but still turn off at random. Sometimes it won't stay on for more than a few seconds w.o. the battery
- Sometimes played graphics-intensive games for multiple hours before it shut off
- After the computer shuts down, I've removed the battery, left it alone for a while, then plugged the battery back in and started it successfully, ensuring that it wasn't the battery's charge that causes the shutdown (this feels like it's consistent w/ a heating issue).

Sometimes, `curr1` in the below screenshot goes from 2.9A to 2.91A, but that seems like a low enough fluctuation to not matter much?
[Screenshot of "lm-sensors" output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmaRi.png)

It seems to shut down at total random. Are there any other causes I can troubleshoot here? I've read through a bunch of different threads w/ the same issue, but none of the solutions therein have helped.

Comment: How old is the battery? Dying battery would be the prime cause of a lot of your symptoms - failing to provide full output when needed. The charger alone can't keep up [it's not designed to] so you get a brownout crash.

Comment: @Tetsujin The battery's about 4 years old (as old as the laptop). Is that a typical lifespan for a battery?

Comment: It would make sense why it shuts down more often on Windows, too! Since I only ever play games on Windows

Comment: Pretty much. I know there are battery tester apps for Mac, idk about for Windows. You could see if you could find one. They check the battery's reported charge against data over time so get reasonably accurate over time. Once it claims 60-70% 'life' then you're due a new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah! yeah it looks like the capacity is at about 60%. It's intended capacity is about 60mWh and it's full charge capacity now is at 38mWh. Looks like it's time for a new battery! Thanks for the help, man. If you write down your comment in an answer proper, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect the battery is dying.

Once it drops below a certain percentage of 'new' it can fail to provide full output when needed. The charger alone can't keep up [it's not designed to] so you get a brownout crash.

I know there are battery tester apps for Mac, idk about for Windows. You could see if you could find one. They check the battery's reported charge against data over time so get reasonably accurate over time.
Once it claims 60-70% 'life' then you're due a new battery.